# How much does volume change when pressure change by 3 atm?

Tags: thermodynamics

I have a problem where I have cylinder cut into two parts with a piston which don't let heat exchange between the two parts .

Both contain 2L of a perfect gaz at a constant pressure of 1 atm in each part and at temperature 290 K.

We assume that the piston can move freely with no friction, we heat up the first part by 3 atm through a resistor .

I need to determine the final perssure, volume and temperature of each part .

**My approach:**

I have the initial pressure and the change $\delta P = 3 atm$ so the final pressure in the first part is obviously 4 atm , and since the pressure got up it's a compression in the first part, but How can I find how much volume was compressed from the first volume ?

Comment: Have you tried to use the perfect gas law? (pV=nRT)

Comment: Yes but I do not have the final temperature  neither the final volume to find one of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the trick is to write down your equations and try to find the solutions from that.

Initially, we have a pair of “equal” ideal gases. Let’s label each by 1 and 2. Since they start out the same, they have the same number $n$ of particles. We can now write the gas law for each:

$$p_1V_1=nRT_1,$$
$$p_2V_2=nRT_2,$$

Which gives

$$\frac{p_1V_1}{T_1}=\frac{p_2V_2}{T_2}.$$

Now, since they share the same cylinder divided by a piston, the total volume $V_1+V_2=\mathrm{constant}=4\mathrm L=V_0$. We can also say that, since there is just a free piston dividing them, such piston is always at mechanical equilibrium, with both gases pushing it with the same pressure $p=p_1=p_2$.

We just need a last bit of information: the gas on the non heated side transforms adiabatically, so $p_2V_2^\gamma=p_0\left(\frac{V_0}{2}\right)^\gamma$.

We can now solve these equations for all the necessary parameters. Go ahead and try!